# Template that knows its own template parameters template

Tags: c++, templates

I have a Resource class that is template, the Compare is any class that can be compared.

I have a ResourceManager< Resource >

However I can't figure out how to make the ResourceManager know about the Compare template from the Resource.

What is the template syntax for this.  I managed to get this

```
template< template< class Compare > class ResType, class Compare >
class ResourceManager
```

But that makes the callsite look like the following which I don't want.

```
ResourceManager< Resource<Compare>, Compare> manager;
```

I want to do

```
ResourceManager<Resource<Compare>> manager;
```

I need to be able to make a Compare object inside the resource manager.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to do this, and the approach used by the STL, is to have the `Resource` template class expose its template argument as a public `typedef`, which you can then easily refer to within the `ResourceManager` template:

```
template<class Compare>
class Resource {
    // ...
  public:
    typedef Compare compare;
};

template<class Resource>
class ResourceManager {
    // return an instance of Resource's Compare type
    typename Resource::compare comp() const {
        return typename Resource::compare();
    }
};
```

Comment: An other way involves specialization, but the above method is better.  Yet another way is adl based overloads like `std::begin` which allows external retrofits of a type.

Answer (score 0):

There is the solution which uses template specialization:

```
template < class >
class ResourceManager;

template < template < class > class ResType, class Compare >
class ResourceManager< ResType<Compare> >
{
public:
    // implementation of ResourceManager template   
};
```